# How to compare two JSON String by data type of values, it should ignore exact values and it should also ignore length of array as per below example

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

Here i have used library

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.11.0'
```

while comparing JSON by below code

```
String actualResponse = "{\n" +
            "    \"employee\":\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"1212\",\n" +
            "        \"fullName\": \"John Miles\",\n" +
            "        \"age\": 34,\n" +
            "        \"skills\": [\"Java\", \"C++\", \"Python\"]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";

        String expectedResponse = "{\n" +
                "    \"employee\":\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"id\": \"1212\",\n" +
                "        \"age\": 34,\n" +
                "        \"fullName\": \"John Miles\",\n" +
                "        \"skills\": [\"Java\", \"C++\"] \n" +
                "    } \n" +
                "}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode actualObj1 = mapper.readTree(actualResponse);
        JsonNode actualObj2 = mapper.readTree(expectedResponse);

        assertEquals(actualObj1, actualObj2);
```

by running above code, the Assertion is failing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<{"employee":{"id":"1212","fullName":"John Miles","age":34,"skills":["Java","C++","Python"]}}> but was:<{"employee":{"id":"1212","age":34,"fullName":"John Miles","skills":["Java","C++"]}}>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
    at JsonComparision.EndpointJsonMatcher.verifyJsonInteraction(EndpointJsonMatcher.java:47)
    at JsonComparision.EndpointJsonMatcher.main(EndpointJsonMatcher.java:37)
```

in above example Assertion is failing because length of `skills` array is mismatching,
i am searching for a solution so that it can ignore array length while comparing, and it should only compare by data type of value.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want exact comparisons? When creating unit tests this seems a little unreasonable.

Comment: If you just want to compare the structure of json objects (i.e. the poperty names and types) you might need to roll your own or look for a library that extracts the structure (not if json-schema would be able to provide this) and then you compare those structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import static JsonNeastedComp.JsonStructure.GetJsonMap;

public class CompareJsonStruct1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String actual = "{\n" +
        "    \"employee\":\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        \"id\": \"1212\",\n" +
        "        \"fullName\": \"John Miles\",\n" +
        "        \"age\": 34,\n" +
        "        \"skills\": [\"Java\", \"C++\", \"Python\"]\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";

        String expected = "{\n" +
            "    \"employee\":\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"1212\",\n" +
            "        \"age\": 34,\n" +
            "        \"fullName\": \"John Miles\",\n" +
            "        \"skills\": [\"Java\", \"C++\"] \n" +
            "    } \n" +
            "}";

        HashMap actual_structure = GetJsonMap(actual);

        HashMap expected_structure = GetJsonMap(expected);

        boolean result = expected_structure.equals(actual_structure);

            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Matched!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Un-matched!");
            }
    }    
}


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testcontainers.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import org.testcontainers.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonStructure {

    static HashMap actual_map;

    public static HashMap GetJsonMap(String actual) throws Exception {

        actual_map = new HashMap();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<String> all_keys_actual = getKeysInJsonUsingMaps(actual, objectMapper);
        all_keys_actual = all_keys_actual.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        JSONObject inputJSONOBject = new JSONObject(actual);

        for (String key : all_keys_actual) {
            getValueOf(inputJSONOBject, key);
        }
        return actual_map;
    }

// In HashMap, Actual Value will be replaced by it's Datatype

    public static void parseObject(JSONObject json, String key) {

        if(json.get(key) instanceof JSONArray){
            actual_map.put(key,"JSONArray");
        } else if (json.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            actual_map.put(key,"JSONObject");
        } else if(json.get(key) instanceof String){
            actual_map.put(key,"String");
        } else if(json.get(key) instanceof Integer){
            actual_map.put(key,"Integer");
        }

    }
    public static List<String> getKeysInJsonUsingMaps(String json, ObjectMapper mapper) throws Exception {
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> jsonElements = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
        getAllKeys(jsonElements, keys);
        return keys;
    }



// Getting all the keys (including nested keys)
    public static void getAllKeys(Map<String, Object> jsonElements, List<String> keys) {

        jsonElements.entrySet()
                .forEach(entry -> {
                    keys.add(entry.getKey());
                    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                        getAllKeys(map, keys);
                    } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof List) {
                        List<?> list = (List<?>) entry.getValue();
                        list.forEach(listEntry -> {
                            if (listEntry instanceof Map) {
                                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) listEntry;
                                getAllKeys(map, keys);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }

    // Getting value of all the keys (including nested keys value)
    public static void getValueOf(JSONObject json, String key) {
        boolean exists = json.has(key);
        Iterator< ? > keys;
        String nextKeys;
        if (!exists) {
            keys = json.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                nextKeys = (String) keys.next();
                try {
                    if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        if (exists == false) {
                            getValueOf(json.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                        }
                    } else if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            String jsonarrayString = jsonarray.get(i).toString();
                            JSONObject innerJSOn = new JSONObject(jsonarrayString);
                            if (exists == false) {
                                getValueOf(innerJSOn, key);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            parseObject(json, key);
        }
    }
}
```